# How to strip whitespace inside <xsl:attribute> tag?

Tags: xml, xslt

In an XSLT stylesheet, how can I remove leading and trailing whitespace inside a `<xsl:attribute>` tag?

For example, the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:element name="myelement">
    <xsl:attribute name="myattribute">
      attribute value
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

outputs:

```
<myelement myattribute="&#10;      attribute value&#10;    "/>
```

whilst I would like it to output:

```
<myelement myattribute="attribute value"/>
```

Is there any way to accomplish that other than collapsing the `<xsl:attribute>` start and end tags in a single line?

Because if the attribute value is not a plain line of text but the result of some complex calculation (for example using  or  tags), then collapsing all the code in one line to avoid the leading and trailing whitespace would result in a horribly ugly stylesheet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could wrap the text by xsl:text or xsl:value-of:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="myelement">
        <xsl:attribute name="myattribute">
            <xsl:text>attribute value</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="myelement">
        <xsl:attribute name="myattribute">
            <xsl:value-of select="'attribute value'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Is this useful for you?
Otherwise please explain your problem in using a single line.

Please take notice of the comment of Michael Kay, it explains the problem to the point!

Comment: The problem is that if the attribute value is a result of some complex calculation, for example with `<xsl:choose>` elements, then collapsing all the code in one line to get the desired result would make the stylesheet look horribly ugly.

Comment: You can use linebreaks between xsl:attribute and xsl:choose.
You just have to avoid linebreaks in text nodes.
All linebreaks in text node will be found in the output.
All linebreaks between xsl-elements will be discarded.

Comment: OK, I got it. In my real-life case the `<xsl:choose>` was "flanked" by text nodes; wrapping each in a `<xsl:text>` effectively removes the whitespace. Problem solved, thanks!

Comment: Remember that whitespace text nodes are collapsed anyway. The only issue is with whitespace adjacent to non-whitespace. To get rid of that, you need to wrap the significant text in xsl:text.